# detecting server-side redirect traffic via javascript on destination page

Tags: javascript, redirect

Here's the problem:

There's a webpage "A".

There's a link on the webpage A that a user clicks.  Let's call the URL of this link "B".

"B" is actually a server-side redirect which takes the user to a webpage "C".

Webpage "C" is on another website and not related to "A" or "B".  However, "C" would like to determine via javascript that the user came from "B".  When using document.referrer, we get "A" when in fact the user was redirected through "B".

The questions is: how do we determine via client-side javascript that the user came "thru" B and what that URL was?

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing you can do here with JavaScript since it reads what the server returns.